# update angles of multiple pie on map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, pie-chart

I'm building a very complex visualization with pie charts on a Choropleth world map. You can cycle through the years and the data gets updated. I managed to update the size of the pies but I have difficulties updating the angles because my data structure is quite different from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410. I don't know how the data update would work in my case.
Thank you for any help

here is my code to build the pies:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()

(some more code here ...)

function ready(error, world, water_pc,cotton_pc,water_total,cotton_total) {
    (some more code here ...)

    var pie = d3.layout.pie();

    var piegroup = g.selectAll(".pie")
      .data(water_pc) 
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class","pie")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return ("translate(" + projection([d.lon,d.lat])[0] + "," +
          projection([d.lon,d.lat])[1] + ")");
    });

    arc
        .outerRadius(function (d,i) {
            return radius(data_water_pc()[this.parentNode.__data__.id][0]+data_water_pc()[this.parentNode.__data__.id][1]);
        })
        .innerRadius(0);

    var arcs = piegroup.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d) {return pie(data_water_pc()[d.id]); })
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }) // store the initial angles
        .attr("class","slice")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorWater(i); });

    (some more code here ...)
```

and this is my update function

```
    var update_total = function() {

        var piegroup = g.selectAll(".pie")
          .transition()

        arc
           .outerRadius(function (d,i) {
              return radius_total(data_water_total()[this.parentNode.__data__.id][0]+data_water_total()[this.parentNode.__data__.id][1]);
           })

        var arcs = piegroup.selectAll("path")
           .transition().duration(150)
           .attr("d", arc)
           //.attrTween("d", arcTween); // when I use this the size of the pies is not calculated anymore
    }
(some more code here ...)
```

and at the end I have my arc tween function:

```
function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the current code is not working? Is it not updating at all or is only the transition not working?

Comment: Hi Lars, on first load everything works fine. but when I select another year with different values the pie segments are not updating at all. I calculate the radius of the pies by the sum of all pie segments ... this update is working including transition.

Comment: Are you binding the new data to the arc segments?

Comment: No, that's actually my question because I don't know how. I tried to put 

    .data(function(d) {return pie(data_water_pc()[d.id]); })

again in my update function but then I get the error:
"undefined is not a function"

I guess the problem is my function data_water_pc() but I don't want to change it because everything is working fine except the update of the pie segments ... seems to be a very special case.

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) should help.

Comment: Thanks, this is the example I was trying to work with (see my first post) but the data structure is very different from mine and I don't know how and where exactly bind my data in the update function because I'm calling my values with a function data_water_pc()[d.id]